# Routing for Home Page and URL's for Website

Tags: angularjs, url-routing, ionic-framework

I'm creating a website from multiple html files that are linked together with the ionic framework and am using AngularJS to transfer between states. I was wondering what the # means in a href and what role it plays in state transfer. If I have a href on a text like

```
<a href="#/app/page2">hi</a>
```

is there a way to configure the url so that instead of saying `localhost/index.html#/app/page2`, it would just say `localhost/index.html/page2` without the `"#/app"`? I've tried

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

First, what means `#` in an url

> Any URL that contains a # character is a fragment URL. The portion of
>   the URL to the left of the # identifies a resource that can be
>   downloaded by a browser and the portion on the right, known as the
>   fragment identifier, specifies a location within the resource

Read more here -> [source](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/)

Putting that in other words: the portion after `#` can be "served" without making a whole http request. In fact that portion after `#` is never sent in any http request.

By default angularjs works with `#` in the urls. It means that angular router will fetch urls only if they have #. Then in your controller, you can catch the request and fetch your required data using ajax.

```
http://example.com/#/about
http://example.com/#/contact
```

You can disable it by enabling `html5mode`, you can do it putting this in your router config:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

So then your urls should looks like these and angular router should works fine.

```
http://example.com/about
http://example.com/contact
```

I would recommend not using # urls, is kinda old. My option is working using normal urls.

Comment: I see. What do you mean by using normal urls? Would you advise using ng-click rather than <a href> tag?

Comment: @user3226932 no no, you can use without #, just `href="/your/url"`. ng-click  is about click handler, not urls.

Comment: i tried putting $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); in my config and even tried putting   <base href="/"> inside the index.html header but it didn't work

Comment: still doesn't work. also, putting <base href="/"> inside the index.html header seems to be throwing an error in that it won't load the html pages.

Comment: @user3226932 can u post your router code and what are u using as backend?